# admob add as notification in Android

Tags: android, admob, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, airpush

How to add addmob add as notification service to the Android app. Basically banner can be displayed as a notification service. Is that possible. If so how?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob can't do that. To add ads in the notification bar you should add the SDK of Airpush

http://www.airpush.com/

IMHO is an absolute error add this type of ads and you should know that your downloads and installs will decrease. It's a very creepy type of ads. Only in my opinion

Comment: thanks for the reply. What will be the alternative solutions for an app based on notifications. Because in my app user will rarely use the main linear layout interface. Anyway airpush seems to be a good solution. But I do not understand the error that you are talking about.

Comment: Using airpush or alternatives to display ads in the notification bar a very bad idea. Many users including myself do not want to see notifications randomly appearing just to show an advertisement, and any app that does this is removed from my device and I know many others users would do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

No longer you can add advertisements in notification according to [Google Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

Refered from [here](http://phandroid.com/2013/09/30/google-play-notification-ads-policy/)